# add a search bar on a page and limit it to search only under post titles?

Tags: views

I wand to add a search bar on a page called "dictionary" and want to limit it to post titles. I mean it should search only texts in posts tiles not the whole posts contents. Please explain me clearly step by step how to do it.

Regards
Ismail

Comment: create a view and add a filter 'Title' text contains.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom_search module.

By this module you can create customize search form that searching on custome content type and custome fields on content type.